# How to add a new audio (not mixing) into a videos using ffmpeg (Batch Processing)?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, debian, codec

I'm looking for a solution to add a new audio (not mixing) into a multiple videos using ffmpeg.

I have 3 directories:

**1**. **videos** (contains *.mp4 videos)

**2**. **audio** (contains single audio.mp3 file)

**3**. **ready** (output folder)

For single video processing I'm using following command:

`ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -codec copy -shortest output.avi`

My goal is to add a single audio (not mixing) into all videos in /videos/ directory using ffmpeg and save the new files in /ready/ keeping the orginal file names. Is this possible with ffmpeg?

Thank you

Comment: This is a shell issue, not ffmpeg. You need to loop over all video inputs and for each iteration, select one video file and mux it with audio and save to ready folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy method is to navigate to `videos` directory then execute a simple *for loop* with parameter expansion:

```
cd videos
for f in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -i ../audio/audio.mp3 -c copy -shortest "../ready/${f%.*}.avi"; done
```